# How shift Request Focus to next textfield in Jetpack compose

Tags: focus, android-jetpack-compose

My requirement is when I enter 1 digit in text field after entering it should be shifted to next text field. Everywhere I got the answer like this.

In short I'm looking for similar functionality like onTextChangeListener in android

[Request Focus on TextField in jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181930/request-focus-on-textfield-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code should give a basic idea.

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun OtpScreen() {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val (digit1, setDigit1) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val (digit2, setDigit2) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val (digit3, setDigit3) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val (digit4, setDigit4) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = digit1,
    ) {
        if (digit1.isNotEmpty()) {
            focusManager.moveFocus(
                focusDirection = FocusDirection.Next,
            )
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = digit2,
    ) {
        if (digit2.isNotEmpty()) {
            focusManager.moveFocus(
                focusDirection = FocusDirection.Next,
            )
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = digit3,
    ) {
        if (digit3.isNotEmpty()) {
            focusManager.moveFocus(
                focusDirection = FocusDirection.Next,
            )
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = digit1,
            onValueChange = {
                setDigit1(it)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp),
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = digit2,
            onValueChange = {
                setDigit2(it)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp),
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = digit3,
            onValueChange = {
                setDigit3(it)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp),
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = digit4,
            onValueChange = {
                setDigit4(it)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.width(64.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I try to revered enter a value it's not revered .